# Android keypad key press overlay

Tags: android, overlay

I am curious about how can I implement the following overlay on some button or key press as shown in following image? I am implementing custom keypad...needed this thing for the same.

[image]

EDIT:

So, I have implemented a keypad like following using a Gridview.

[image]

Now, I am trying to put some overlay (on click) as in default keyboard.

Thanks :)

Comment: lovely question I want to something new

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is "key preview" 
I assume you're using `KeyboardView` to create your custom keyboard. You can enable the key preview by calling [setPreviewEnabled(boolean previewEnabled)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#setPreviewEnabled(boolean)) it should be something like that : `mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true);`

Edit:

I think this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) will help you in your implementation and explains more in details what I was trying to.

First you create a layout for the keyboard, generally it contains only a keyboardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview" />
```

And then you create another layout for the preview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffff00"   
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp">    
</TextView>
```

After that you design your keyboard in your case something like that:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"  
    android:keyHeight="60dp">
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
   </Row>
   <Row>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
   </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Finally in your java code you inflate your keyboardView or you get it by its id if it's included in a fragment or activity layout. and you set the keyboard that you designed to it.

```
kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.numeric);
kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
```

best of luck.

Comment: I am not using keyboard view. I created my own keypad using views. But to create an awesome experience with key presses I wanted to implemented such overlay sorta thing with normal views press. Thanks

Comment: I don't get what you mean by using views! Can you add more details on how you're creating your custom keybord? 
Normally you'd have to create an xml keybord with rows and keys, an xml layout for the keyboard, and an another for the preview.

Comment: MAB, more details added.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PopupWindow` for the key preview functionality(Actually I did the same thing on my last IME project).

I recommend you using a child class of `KeyboardView` because it offers you lots of funtions to make things eay.Each time the `key` is pressed, the `onPressed` is called back and then you know which one is pressed. And dive into the source  code of `KeyboardView`, you can learn where to place your `popupWindow`from the class.

Just a little effort. But if your class doesn't derive from `KeyboardView`(like using a `GridView`), you will have to take more time to figure it out.Anyway, the source code is a good start.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, the PopupWindow, I will try this one. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350654/popup-keyboard-issue-in-android-when-column-limits-are-specified see: